# Como anexar arquivo em e-mail?

Tags: email, perl

Tenho esse código em Perl que envia emails de uma lista com assunto e corpo, preciso de um que faça isso mas que seja possível anexar algum arquivo da minha escolha. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$ARGC=@ARGV;
if ($ARGC !=4) {
   printf "Você digitou de uma forma errada. Siga as instruções.\n";
   printf "INSTRUÇÕES - UND3F1N3D\n";
   printf "perl $0 <mailist> <remetente\@mail.com> <assunto> <corpo.html>\n";
   printf "Exemplo: perl $0 lista01.txt peu\@msn.com Ola index.html\n";
   exit(1);
}

$mailtype = "content-type: text/html";
$sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$sender = $ARGV[1];
$subject = $ARGV[2];
$efile = $ARGV[0];
$emar = $ARGV[0];
open(FOO, $ARGV[3]);
@foo = <FOO>;
$corpo = join("\n", @foo);
open (BANDFIT, "$emar") || die "Can't Open $emar";
$cont=0;

while(<BANDFIT>) {
   ($ID,$options) = split(/\|/,$_);
   chop($options);
   foreach ($ID) {
      $recipient = $ID;
      open (SENDMAIL, "| $sendmail -t");
      print SENDMAIL "$mailtype\n";
      print SENDMAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
      print SENDMAIL "From: $sender\n";
      print SENDMAIL "To: $recipient\n\n";
      print SENDMAIL "$corpo\n\n";
      close (SENDMAIL);
      $cont=$cont+1;
      printf "$cont Enviado para $recipient";
   }
}
close(BANDFIT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isto eu acredito que você terá que usar o modulo `MIME::Lite`, baixe ele em http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz

> **Nota:** se o link estiver desatualizado acesse por aqui http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/ e procure com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> por `MIME-LITE`)

Comando para compilar e instalar:

```
$tar xvfz MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
$cd MIME-Lite-3.030
$perl Makefile.PL
$make
$make install
```

### Dependencias

Para usar o MIME-LITE é necessário instalar os seguintes modulos:

- [MIME::Types](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3A%3ATypes)
- [Mail::Address](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail%3A%3AAddress)
- [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/MIME-Base64-3.15/Base64.pm)
- [MIME::QuotedPrint](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3A%3AQuotedPrint)
- [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.06/lib/Net/SMTP.pm)
- [Email::Date::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Date-Format-1.005/lib/Email/Date/Format.pm)

Um exemplo simples de anexo:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$cc = 'efgh@mail.com';
$from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'email de teste';
$message = 'Corpo do email de teste';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Type     => 'multipart/mixed'
                 );

# Add your text message.
$msg->attach(Type         => 'text',
             Data         => $message
            );

# Specify your file as attachement.
$msg->attach(Type        => 'image/gif', #Mimetype do arquivo
             Path        => '/tmp/logo.gif', #Pasta do arquivo
             Filename    => 'logo.gif', #Nome do arquivo
             Disposition => 'attachment'
            );       
$msg->send;
print "Email enviado com sucesso\n";
```

Documentação: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm

Modificando o seu código existente:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;

$ARGC=@ARGV;
if ($ARGC !=4) {
   printf "Você digitou de uma forma errada. Siga as instruções.\n";
   printf "INSTRUÇÕES - UND3F1N3D\n";
   printf "perl $0 <mailist> <remetente\@mail.com> <assunto> <corpo.html>\n";
   printf "Exemplo: perl $0 lista01.txt peu\@msn.com Ola index.html\n";
   exit(1);
}

$sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$sender = $ARGV[1];
$subject = $ARGV[2];
$efile = $ARGV[0];
$emar = $ARGV[0];
open(FOO, $ARGV[3]);
@foo = <FOO>;
$corpo = join("\n", @foo);
open (BANDFIT, "$emar") || die "Can't Open $emar";
$cont=0;

while(<BANDFIT>) {
   ($ID,$options) = split(/\|/,$_);
   chop($options);
   foreach ($ID) {
      $recipient = $ID;
        $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                         From     => $sender,
                         To       => $recipient,
                         Subject  => $subject,
                         Type     => 'multipart/mixed'
                         );

        # Add your text message.
        $msg->attach(Type         => 'text/html',
                     Data         => $corpo
                    );

        # Specify your file as attachement.
        $msg->attach(Type        => 'image/gif', #Mimetype do arquivo
                     Path        => '/tmp/logo.gif', #Pasta do arquivo
                     Filename    => 'logo.gif', #Nome do arquivo
                     Disposition => 'attachment'
                    );       
        $msg->send;

      $cont=$cont+1;
      printf "$cont Enviado para $recipient";
   }
}
close(BANDFIT);
```

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme, nesse seu exemplo enviaria 1 email de cada vez e n me serviria, eu vou tentar fazer a junção dos dois, mas n entendo nada de perl.
Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Mas aí não seria mais de um anexo ao inves de varios emails?
O primeiro código carrega os emails a partir de uma mailing list.

Comment: Obrigadão cara, vou testar aqui... me quebrou uma arvore hahah

Comment: me retornou esse erro [root@b04s12 ~]# perl envio.pl lts.txt "teste@hotmail.com" "Teste" teste.html
Can't locate object method "new" via package "MIME::Lite" (perhaps you forgot to load "MIME::Lite"?) at envio.pl line 28, <BANDFIT> line 1.

Comment: @KynLeonardo Falha minha, esqueci de adicionar no exemplo o `use MIME::Lite;`, note que se tiver alguma duvida olhe o primeiro exemplo mais simples, ele pode te ajudar. Editei a resposta, basta adicionar `use MIME::Lite;` após o `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`

Comment: Me retornou outro erro


Can't locate Email/Date/Format.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/MIME/Lite.pm line 1100, <BANDFIT> line 1.

Comment: @KynLeonardo é necessário instalar algumas dependências, no caso MIME::Types,
Mail::Address,
MIME::Base64,
MIME::QuotedPrint,
Net::SMTP e
Email::Date::Format. Veja eu editei a resposta e adicionei os links destas dependências. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Irei testar, obg de novo...
Assim que puder, darei o feedback

Comment: Tudo ok, testado e aprovado... @guilherme muito obrigado.

Comment: Para instalar o módulo sugeria `sudo cpan MIME::Lite` que trata de tudo inclusivé o fecho das dependências. (+1)

Comment: @JJoao Obrigado, tenho costume de usar `make`, as vezes nem imagino que existem atalhos :) Parece bem útil.